# Non-Parametric Test help needed

Tags: r, statistics, static-methods

I want to test whether "takeover premiums" are differently influenced by the variable "Beta" during economic crisis vs normal periods. To test that, I used a Generalised Least Squares Regression (GLS) because the takeover premiums are not normally distributed. However, I understand that one underlying assumption is a linear relationship between the dependent variables and the takeover premiums and this is not the case. **Can I use a different test to test my hypothesis?**

Furthermore, I'm not sure whether I used the **right code in R**:

```
financial_model <- gls(`X1.Month.Equity.Premium` ~ crisis + Beta, 
                       data = financial_subset, method = "ML")
linearHypothesis(financial_model, c("crisis + Beta = 0"))
```

Does the Code above test a linear relationship between the independent variable `X1.Month.Equity.Premium` and the two dependent variables or just between crisis and Beta?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you post some plots of your data? For ex. `pairs(financial_subset)` with these 3 variables.

Comment: I hope the following helps. I hope it is what you need. Plots for the data:
[pairs][1]
[takeover premium][2]
[crisis][3]
[Beta][4]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcHZQ.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaG6c.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ISfy.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgRFP.png

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.